# stop jquery live from hooking all the children

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I can't stop the stupid thing from firing off an event when hovering over the children of item.
I only want the event to fire via the `div.item` element, not the `div.itemChild`. This is driving me nuts please help.

event.stopPropigation does not work. nor does `if(!$(event.source).is('itemChild'))`, for some reason `is()` alway returns false.

**HTML**

```
<div id="items">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="itemChild">
        </div>
        <div class="itemChild">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
//on hover event for each post
$('div.item', '#items').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event){
    if (event.type == 'mouseover'){
        //fire mouseover handler
    }
    else{
        //fire mouseout handler
    }
});
```

Is there a way to stop live from firing when hovering the children of `div.item`?

By the way the children of `div.item` cover it completely.

Basically I want this to act like .hover() but bind to things loaded via ajax.

Comment: `stop jquery live from hooking all the children.` - This sounds like a matter for child protective services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not binding to the children. It's bubbling up to the parent.

Also, your syntax isn't correct. This:

```
$("div.item", "div.items")...
```

is saying "find me all the divs with class item that are descendants of divs with class of items. But you have no such divs (with class items). You have a div with an ID of items.

Combining all this try:

```
$("#items div").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
  if ($(event.source).hasClass("itemChild")) {
    return false;
  } else if (event.type == "mouseover") {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
});
```

Or, alternatively:

```
$("#items > div.item").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
  if (!($this).is("div.item")) {
    return false;
  }
  ...
});
```

Basically, there are many ways to skin this cat but like I said in the first sentence, you have to understand that events bubble up until the handlers stop propagation, either directly (by calling `event.stopPropagation()` or by returning `false` from the event handler, which is equivalent to `event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();`).

Also, if you're doing `mouseenter` and `mouseout` you might as well just use the `hover()` event that does both of those:

```
$("#items > div.item").live("hover", function(event) {
  // mouseenter
}, function(event) {
  // mouseout
});
```

Comment: @Robert wow, downvoting people trying to help you. way to get no help at all.

Comment: Yes well you didn't have anything helpful in your post when I down voted it. You've since added more and I've removed the down vote.
Thanks.

Comment: @Robert actually what I wrote was succinct and correct. Without bothering to try and understand it or waiting to see if there was more, you simply downvoted. Most times you'll find people will just delete their answers when faced with this sort of impatient rudeness. If someone bothers to take the time to try and help you, the least you can do is show them some respect and patience before jumping the gun.